# Is there a solution for this case 'When I drag the edge to a certain extent, the central QDockWidget is hidden.'?

Tags: qt5, qdockwidget

When I drag the edge to a certain extent, the central QDockWidget is hidden. I recorded the screen when i operated this Qt Demo wrote by me. The recording screen video link is as follow:

[recording screen](http://note.youdao.com/yws/public/resource/30d0cab13287a19b00980264e903a6e3/xmlnote/E9B7A59567E54106A59519D29D582474/57094)

---

development environment: QT5 & Qt Creator 4.6.1 & Win10

---

There is two .ui files, one is the mainwindow.ui ,another is the secondmainwindow.ui.

mainwindow.cpp constructor function:

```cpp
    ui->setupUi(this);
    ui->mdiArea->setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(Qt::ScrollBarAsNeeded);
    ui->mdiArea->setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(Qt::ScrollBarAsNeeded);

    QMdiSubWindow *subWindow = ui->mdiArea->addSubWindow(new SecondMainwindow());
    // hide title
    subWindow->setWindowFlags(Qt::FramelessWindowHint);

    subWindow->showMaximized();
    // 
    setCentralWidget(ui->mdiArea);
    // 
    setDockNestingEnabled(true);
```

secondmainwindow.cpp constructor function:

```cpp
    ui->setupUi(this);
    // 
    QWidget* p = takeCentralWidget();
    if(p) {
        delete p;
        p = nullptr;
    }
```

the all QDockWidget are generated by the Qt Designer software, And all parameters are default with QDockWidget. so, Are there some details I didn't notice? Thanks.